# Data Binding in winforms project using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

There are two examples/tutorials I have been running through to educate myself.

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx

Both have conflicting methods or ways of doing data binding.  In tutorial(1), they are saying to bind using EntityDataSource.  I have read that this control is outdated in version 6 and if I wanted to use EntityDataSource I would need to use EF5.  In tutorial(2) uses a different method of data binding.

What is the recommended way to perform data binding in a winforms application using Entity Framework version 6?  If the answer is you can't then so be it but it appears that there would be some advantages to using EF6 in our project so this is why I am asking. Many thanks to those lending their comments and suggestions!

Comment: If starting means starting from scratch I would absolutely not use WinForms.

Comment: Further, binding objects from the DAL directly is good for small apps, not for "rather large projects". There you want decent separation of concerns, i.e. view models, services, domain/DAL (the latter two can overlap with EF).

Comment: The Load() is an extension method that you can find in System.Entity.

Comment: @AndrewBarber  There is only one question in my post which is...What is the recommend way to perform data binding in a winforms application using EF6?  If I can be more specific and less broad please advise.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: If anyone wants to know.  The 2nd link listed above is what I seem to find as the recommended way to perform effective databinding using a gridview with EF6.  In the tutorial it doesn't describe ProductContext which might trip some up. They are referring to the "Entities" class that is auto created. Thanks for the input everyone!

Comment: This is too broad - and also primarily opinion-based - because there are *many, many* ways to do what you are asking. That's the very definition of the "too broad" close reason.

Comment: Meh, whatever...I found my own answer and hopefully this post will help someone else.  Contributing > Marking Question [Closed]

Comment: I really love this plattform as good source of information. But it's annoying that many questions get closed without helping people. It's all about helping people and working together. Ok, the question is broad - but there are many broad questions answered in so. And I love them, because they can give you a hint and point you in the right direction. Bytheway the questioneer is asking for advise and the answer is: many many ways. What about your favorite way? What else have you seen? Is there a questions which fits better? I'm sure A.B. answered a lot of questions in the sense of so. Not this.